# Ionic FileTransfer not reaching server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm having trouble getting an Ionic 3 basic example code working. It uses the Cordova plugins for the camera and file transfers to upload an image to a server (Django Rest Framework). The front-end is to run on Android.

home.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NavController,
  ToastController,
  Platform,
  LoadingController,
  Loading
} from 'ionic-angular';

import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import {Transfer, TransferObject} from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import {FilePath} from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import {Camera} from '@ionic-native/camera';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  lastImagePath: string = null;
  lastImage: string = null;
  loading: Loading;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          private camera: Camera,
          private transfer: Transfer,
          private file: File,
          private filePath: FilePath,
          public toastCtrl: ToastController,
          public platform: Platform,
          public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
  }

  public clickTakePicture() {
    // Create options for the Camera Dialog
    var options = {
      quality: 80,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    // Get the data of an image
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
    var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.lastImagePath = imagePath;
    this.lastImage = currentName;
    }, (err) => {
      this.presentToast('Error while getting image from camera.');
    });
  }

  private presentToast(text) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: text,
      duration: 4000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  public uploadImage() {
    // Destination URL
    var url = "http://192.168.1.6:8000/api/photo/";

    // File for Upload
    var targetPath = this.lastImagePath;

    // File name only
    var filename = this.lastImage;

    var options = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: filename,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
      params: {'fileName': filename}
    };

    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Uploading...',
    });
    this.loading.present();

    // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
    fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
      this.loading.dismissAll()
      this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded.');
    }, err => {
      this.loading.dismissAll()
      this.presentToast('Error uploading targetPath ' + targetPath);
    });
  }

}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Devdactic Image Upload2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  lastImagePath = {{ lastImagePath }}
  lastImage = {{ lastImage }}

  <img src="{{ lastImagePath }}" style="width: 100%" [hidden]="lastImagePath === null">
  <h3 [hidden]="lastImagePath !== null">Please Select Image!</h3>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons>
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="clickTakePicture()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>Select Image
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="uploadImage()" [disabled]="lastImage === null">
    <ion-icon name="cloud-upload"></ion-icon>Upload
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

My backend server does not even register an attempted access to this. The server registers a GET request if I just use a browser and visit http://192.168.1.6:8000/api/photo/.

The image is displayed on the page once the camera has captured an image but I get the error when I try fileTransfer.upload().

---

Update - There seems to be a different result depending on the way I run the application.

Results of console.log()

```
  console.log("Error " + err.code)
  console.log("Error " + err.source)
  console.log("Error " + err.target)
  console.log("Error " + err.http_status)
  console.log("Error " + err.body)
  console.log("Error " + err.exception)
```

When using ionic cordova run android --debug, I can see a response from my server (HTTP 401) which I can work on.

> 10-10 22:28:23.989 18878 18878 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(131)] "Error
>   3", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (131) 10-10
>   22:28:23.990 18878 18878 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(132)] "Error
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1507642101200.jpg",
>   source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (132) 10-10
>   22:28:23.991 18878 18878 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(133)] "Error
>   http://192.168.1.6:8000/api/photo/", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (133) 10-10 22:28:23.992 18878
>   18878 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(134)] "Error null", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (134) 10-10 22:28:23.992 18878
>   18878 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(135)] "Error null", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (135) 10-10 22:28:23.993 18878
>   18878 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(136)] "Error Broken pipe", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (136)

When using the ionic upload and Legacy Ionic View application there is no response from my server at all and the error fields are null.

> 10-10 23:06:56.199 28933 28933 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(132)] "Error
>   null", source:
>   file:///data/user/0/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//5bdfa3f9/build/main.js
>   (132) 10-10 23:06:56.199 28933 28933 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(133)]
>   "Error null", source:
>   file:///data/user/0/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//5bdfa3f9/build/main.js
>   (133) 10-10 23:06:56.199 28933 28933 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(134)]
>   "Error null", source:
>   file:///data/user/0/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//5bdfa3f9/build/main.js
>   (134) 10-10 23:06:56.200 28933 28933 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(135)]
>   "Error null", source:
>   file:///data/user/0/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//5bdfa3f9/build/main.js
>   (135) 10-10 23:06:56.200 28933 28933 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(136)]
>   "Error null", source:
>   file:///data/user/0/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//5bdfa3f9/build/main.js
>   (136) 10-10 23:06:56.201 28933 28933 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)]
>   "Error null", source:
>   file:///data/user/0/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//5bdfa3f9/build/main.js
>   (137)

Comment: can you console.log the `err` object? and add that to the question?

Comment: Are you sure you can reach the local IP of your computer from your Device?

Comment: Yes I can reach my PC from my device. It seems to only happen when I am using the Legacy Ionic View app now. I've not tried the new Ionic View app because it was buggy the last time I tried.